# Connecting Node.js to MongoDB remotely, what is the url to hit for my API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

So I'm building an application in Node.js/Express/MongoDB and I followed some teamtreehouse tutorials but that was through runnning Node.js through your shell instead of on a remote server. I've set up Node.js and MongoDB on a Digital Ocean Server and it says I'm able to connect however I've tried variances of url's to hit for my api.

Now my application is running from http://joshuaericbenner.me/projects/sideprojects/LinkedInApp/public/

and my file structure is as so:

```
LinkedInAppp
 -> public -> index.html
 -> src
       -> api -> index.js (where the api calls exist)
       -> database.js
```

So my question is, shouldn't I be hitting the endpoint of http://joshuaericbenner.me/projects/sideprojects/LinkedInApp/api/users and get a response?

Currently when I try in Postman I get a response of:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /projects/sideprojects/LinkedInApp/api/users was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at joshuaericbenner.me Port 80</address>
</body>
```

MongoDB connection(database.js):

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/LinkedInUsers',function(err){
if(err){
    console.log("Failed to connect to mongodb");
}
else{
    console.log("Successfully connected to mongodb");
}
});
```

Mongo Output from my server's shell:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
> show dbs
LinkedInUsers  0.078GB
admin          (empty)
local          0.078GB
test           0.078GB
> use LinkedInUsers
switched to db LinkedInUsers
> db.post.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5810e578059f3fc430a6089b"), "formattedName" : "jb"          }
```

Node.js Output when I run my Node.js App:

```
root@joshuaericbenner:/var/www/html/projects/sideprojects/LinkedInApp#    nodejs src/app.js 
Now running on port 8080
Successfully connected to mongodb
```

Express API(index.js as above):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var User = require('../models/user');
var router = express.Router();

//Get All Users
router.get('/users', function (req, res){
User.find({}, function(err, users){
    if(err){
        res.status(500 ).json({message: err.message});
    }
    res.json({users: users});
});
} );
```

App.js
    'use strict';

```
var express = require('express');
var parser = require('body-parser');
var router = require('./api');

var app = express();

require('./database');
require('./seed');

app.use(parser.json());
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8080, function (){
    console.log("Now running on port 8080");
});
```

User Model:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    formattedName: String,
    id: String,
    location: {
        country: {
            code: String
        },
        name: String
    },
    positions:
    {
        values:
        [
            {
                company: {
                    id: Number,
                    location: {
                    name: String
                }
            },
            location: {
                name: String
            },
            id: Number,
            isCurrent: Boolean,
            summary: String,
            title: String
        }
    ]
    },
    publicProfileUrl: String
});

var model = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

Comment: What output are you actually getting when you hit your endpoint? What does the console say?

Comment: Show your User model

Comment: @katylavallee Added. I figured it should work because although I don't have any records with the full schema I have one with formattedName.

Comment: @Soviut My console output is what I wrote under "Postman". And then under that is the Mongo Output from shell and under that is Node.js Output from shell

Comment: Ok, your server (Apache) is serving stuff for requests to `http://joshuaericbenner.me/`, and your Node app is listening on that server on port 8080. First of all, your server currently exposes your source code, if I go to `http://joshuaericbenner.me/projects/sideprojects/LinkedInApp/` I can get your LinkedIn cliend id and secret from `linkedInAjax.js` file. Secondly, you need to tell apache to forward requests from port 80 to port 8080 if you want Node to serve that requests. Don't know about Apache, in Nginx it's a `proxy_pass` directive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your route. you are making a call to `/api/users` while your route is configured for `users`.

```
router.get('/api/users', function (req, res){
User.find({}, function(err, users){
    if(err){
        res.status(500 ).json({message: err.message});
    }
    res.json({users: users});
});
} );
```

Comment: Sorry added my App.js for clarification. Not sure if it changes anything but I thought that my route would be /api/users as I did api.use('/api', router);